# change the default behavior of reactstrap UncontrolledCollapse

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

Is it possible to change the behavior of [reactstrap UncontrolledCollapse](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/collapse/) component to be open by default without using a state handler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Before `reactstrap` v7.0.0** it is not possible to have an uncontrolled collapse which is open by default.

**For versions after `reactstrap` v7.0.0**:

`UncontrolledCollapse` now accepts a prop `defaultOpen`. [Source](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/blob/7.0.0/src/UncontrolledCollapse.js#L9)

You can pass this flag as `true` to keep it open by default.

```
const App = () => (      
   <div className="App">
     <button id="toggler">
        Toggle
     </button>
     <UncontrolledCollapse toggler="#toggler" defaultOpen={true}>
        <Card>
            <CardBody>
              <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
              <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
            </CardBody>
         </Card>
      </UncontrolledCollapse>
    </div>
 );
```

Here is the link to the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-benz-koc2f

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
I want to use the UncontrolledCollapse component without a state handler. Is it possible to reverse the component logic to be open by default and toggle collapse like it works now without any handler?

Comment: Yes, you can use the first approach and pass the `isOpen` as `true` and it will remain open by default. But you won't be able to close it. If you want it to be interactive, you need to pass the handler else it is fine.

Comment: @HardikModha : What happens when we have more than one UncontrolledCollapse component ? In this case all are being toggle. Please suggest.

Comment: @H.Husain Can you please clarify your use case?

Comment: I think your solution is just a normal `Collapse`. Whats the benefit of using `UncontrolledCollapse` here if one has to manage state anyway? It is clear that the original question wanted a reversed `UncontrolledCollapse` with default value open instead of close and no state management. Is it posible anyway?

Comment: @DavidCasillas Yes, Indeed. You are right. It wasn't actually possible to have `UncontrolledCollapse` open by default when I posted the answer. Now it's possible. I've updated my answer to reflect the same Thanks for pointing out.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the property `defaultOpen={true}` in the `UncontrolledCollapse` component.

See sourde code for `UncontrolledCollapse` here https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/blob/master/src/UncontrolledCollapse.js